# Propagate shortcut from window to UserControls in WPF

Tags: c#, wpf

I want to catch shortcuts at the window level with KeyBindings and then raise an event that all UserControls can somehow subscribe to in order to get notified when a shortcut has been issued.

I tried to do this on the window:

```
<Window.InputBindings>
        <KeyBinding Key="M"
                    Command="{x:Static someNamespace:RoutedCommands.ShortcutSingleKeyM}" />
</Window.InputBindings>
```

And then add CommandBindings in the usercontrol to "catch" the command:

```
<UserControl.CommandBindings>
        <CommandBinding Command="{x:Static someNamespace:RoutedCommands.ShortcutSingleKeyM}" Executed="OnShortcutSingleKeyM"></CommandBinding>
</UserControl.CommandBindings>
```

Method `OnShortcutSingleKeyM`in UserControl's is not getting hit. After some reading I now understand RouteCommands bubble up the tree and that might be the reason this approach didn't work.

I need the UserControl to be able to listen to "OnShortcut" events coming from the window. I'm currently implementing it this way:

1. Add an attached property to each user control that wants to listen to such events. Have the container pass a higher level delegate kind of thing to notify the Usercontrol.

Does this make sense? I'm getting the feeling that I'm overthinking this, it should be simpler to achieve.

Answer (score 0):

Propagating from the Window down the tree to UserControls it's not going to work (at least not without major plumbing). I implemented it this way:

- View listens to input (via both `KeyBindings` and `KeyDown` events).
- View owns an object (**ShortcutMcShortcutFace**) that allows UserControls to subscribe to a **OnShortcutEvent** kind of thing.
- UserControls expose `DependencyProperties` of type **ShortcutMcShortcutFace**. The view passes its **ShortcutMcShortcutFace** instance to them. They subscribe to **OnShortcutEvent**.
- UserControls handle the **OnShortcutEvent** (args include a shortcut identifier) whichever way they want.